# Now to convert this strings to date time object in Python or django?

Tags: python, django

Now to convert this strings to date time object in Python or django?

```
2010-08-17T19:00:00Z
2010-08-17T18:30:00Z
2010-08-17T17:05:00Z
2010-08-17T14:30:00Z
2010-08-10T22:20:00Z
2010-08-10T21:20:00Z
2010-08-10T20:25:00Z
2010-08-10T19:30:00Z
2010-08-10T19:00:00Z
2010-08-10T18:30:00Z
2010-08-10T17:30:00Z
2010-08-10T17:05:00Z
2010-08-10T17:05:00Z
2010-08-10T15:30:00Z
2010-08-10T14:30:00Z
```

whrn i do this `datestr=datetime.strptime( datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" )`

it tell me that `unconverted data remains: Z`

Comment: Duplicate of ALL the date parsing questions.  Please read a few of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+date+parsing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use slicing to remove "Z" before supplying the string for conversion

```
datestr=datetime.strptime( datetime[:-1], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" )

>>> test = "2010-08-17T19:00:00Z"
>>> test[:-1]
'2010-08-17T19:00:00'
```

Answer (score 11):

You can parse the strings as-is without the need to slice if you don't mind using the handy [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module. For e.g.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> s = "2010-08-17T19:00:00Z"
>>> parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 17, 19, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Those seem to be [ISO 8601 dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If your timezone is always the same, just remove the last letter before parsing it with strptime (e.g by slicing).

The Z indicates the timezone, so be sure that you are taking that into account when converting it to a datetime of a different timezone. If the timezone can change in your application, you'll have to parse that information also and change the datetime object accordingly.

You could also use the [pyiso8601 module](http://code.google.com/p/pyiso8601/) to parse these ISO dates, it will most likely also work with slighty different ISO date formats. If your data may contain different timezones I would suggest to use this module.

Answer (score 2):

change your format string to ""%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" so that it includes the trailing Z (which makes it no longer unconverted).  Note, however, that this Z perhaps is there to indicate that the time is in UTC which might be something you need to account for otherwise